# Create a new array of all values from an array with step

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to Python. I would like to create a new array, that contains all values from an existing array with the step.

I tried to implement it but I think there is another way to have better performance. Any try or recommendation is highly appreciated.

Ex: Currently, I have:

1. An array: 115.200 values (2D dimension)
2. Step: 10.000

....

```
array([[ 0.2735, -0.308 ],
   [ 0.287 , -0.3235],
   [ 0.2925, -0.324 ],
   [ 0.312 , -0.329 ],
   [ 0.3275, -0.345 ],
   [ 0.3305, -0.352 ],
   [ 0.332 , -0.3465],
   ...
   [ 0.3535, -0.353 ],
   [ 0.361 , -0.3445],
   [ 0.3545, -0.329 ]])
```

**Expectation**: A new array is sliced the array above by step of 10.000.

Below is my code:

```
for x in ecg_data:
    number_samples_by_duration_exp_temp = 10000
    # len(ecg_property.sample) = 115200
    times = len(ecg_property.sample) / number_samples_by_duration_exp_temp
    index_by_time = [int(y)*number_samples_by_duration_exp_temp for y in np.arange(1, times, 1)]
    list = []
    temp = 0
    for z in index_by_time:
        arr_samples_by_duration = ecg_property.sample[temp:z]
        list.append(arr_samples_by_duration)
        temp = z
```

Comment: Is your outer loop necessary? After reviewing the code I don't see the variable `x` being used anywhere which leads me to question the need for it. The only other reason I can think of for why you are doing this is that you need to create an array with the mentioned step size, `x` number of times.

Comment: And if that indeed is the case, then you need to create a list of lists. With this current implementation, you are creating a list, whose information is getting wiped with every iteration of the loop.

Comment: For your 1st comment - You are right. Actually, `x` is used for other businesses, and I omitted it to avoid complicating matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy can not be used for this purpose as `len(ecg_property.sample) #115,200` is not fully divisible by `number_samples_by_duration_exp_temp #10,000` and numpy cannot allow elements of varying lengths :)

You can try list comprehension.

`result_list = [ecg_property.sample[temp :temp+step] for temp in np.arange(times)*step ]`

where
`step=10000` and `times = len(ecg_property.sample) / step`

It can be further modified if needed and as per requirement.

(You can try out each step in above line of code in this answer and see the output to understand each step )
Hope this works out.
ty!

Comment: It works as per my expectation. Can you help correct your answer from `np.range` to `np.arange` ?